# unable to overlap DIVs

Tags: html, css

I'm having a slight issue getting an image in my carousel to overlap over another div. [click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/index.php)

If you click on the red tab, i am trying to the image of the bottle to sit on top of the white box (#section1). I have noticed when i remove `position:relative` from `.rslides` the carousel image does what i want it to do, however the background image i have placed in `#rslides1` goes infront...

I have tweaked around with the z-index property however, i'm still unable to achieve it. Does anyone have a solution to the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem, but if your z-index doesn't work, it's maybe because one of the elements is not positioned (relatively or absolutely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked when i changed my css properties to the following:

```
#header{
    max-width: 1018px;
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
} 

.rslides {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -275px;
    float: left;
    z-index: -1;
 }

.rslides_tabs { 
    margin: 93px auto 0; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 1011px; 
    z-index: 10;
 }
```

Comment: is that my answer? :) or just **very** similar?

Comment: ah sorry, i didn't see your answer

Answer (score 1):

To fix that:

1. Remove `position: relative` from `.rslides`.
2. Add `position: relative; z-index: 10;` to `.rslides_tabs` and `#header`

Answer (score 0):

Use this css to clear the issue:

```
.rslides {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -275px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

**Use the z-index value as z-index:999**